# Как на Java сделать скриншот и отправить на облачный сервис по API

Tags: java, screenshots

```
Main.java

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

```
MyThread.java

public class MyThread extends Thread
{

    @Override
    public void run()
    {

        String ACCESS_TOKEN = "Kq8GMFb34IAAAAAAAAA........SA1E2RnLV01liMzc8v";

        DbxRequestConfig config = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("dropbox/java-tutorial").build();
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());

        for(;;)
        {
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            String date = format.format(new Date());




            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try {
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());
                client.files().uploadBuilder(String.valueOf(os))
                        .uploadAndFinish(is);
            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

                try {
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так? Как сделать скриншот, не создавая сам файл и отправить его в облако?

Comment: А почему вы решили что создаете файл?

Answer (score 0):

```
Main.java

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

```
import com.dropbox.core.DbxException;
import com.dropbox.core.DbxRequestConfig;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.DbxClientV2;
import com.dropbox.core.v2.files.UploadErrorException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String ACCESS_TOKEN = "Kq8GMFb34IAAAAAAAAAAFLk_t5bofhDSRX75rYqV2AIQ0TSA1E2RnLV01liMzc8v";

        DbxRequestConfig config = DbxRequestConfig.newBuilder("dropbox/java-tutorial").build();
        DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config, ACCESS_TOKEN);

        for(;;)
        {
            BufferedImage image = null;
            try {
                image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                String date = format.format(new Date());

                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
                byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

                client.files().uploadBuilder("/" + date + ".png")
                        .uploadAndFinish(is);

                sleep(3250);

            } catch (AWTException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UploadErrorException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DbxException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    }
}
```

client.files().uploadBuilder(**String.valueOf(os)**) - ошибка именно в этой строчке, неправильно задан path